# Javascript: action when a string is not found in an array of objects (if statement)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, if-statement

```
var checkStore=function (book) {
    for (var i=0; i<BookStore.length;i++) {
        if (book==BookStore[i].title) {
            var reply= prompt ('Want to add to your cart?'+ BookStore[i].title);
            if (reply==='yes') {
                Susan.cart.push(BookStore[i]);
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

How to add to my existing code "if the string is not found, then alert the user 'not found!'". Do I used [else] statement or begin a new one? It's not working correctly when I used else-if statement.

Comment: what did your else if statement look like? You can't really use an else statement on your current if, as it would fire for every iteration of the loop. You could have a boolean variable that you check after the iteration to see if anything was found, and alert the user then.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to find the book first, then do your logic:

```
var checkStore = function(book) {
    var found;
    for (var i = 0; i < BookStore.length; i++) {
        if (book == BookStore[i].title) {
            found = BookStore[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        var reply = prompt ('Want to add to your cart?' + found.title);
        if (reply === 'yes') {
            Susan.cart.push(found);
        }
    } else {
        alert('not found!');
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var checkStore=function (book) {
  if(BookStore.indexOf(book) < 0){
    alert('hello, no book');
   } else {
      for (var i=0; i<BookStore.length;i++) {
        if (book==BookStore[i].title) {
          var reply= prompt ('Want to add to your cart?'+ BookStore[i].title);
          if (reply==='yes') {
            Susan.cart.push(BookStore[i]);
          }
        }
     } 
    }
}

}
```

Comment: `BookStore.indexOf()`will iterate the list one more time, plus `book` must match the element `title`...

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are totally valid. You can also just make return points which stop the execution of the function at logical endpoints.

```
var checkStore=function (book) {
    for (var i=0; i<BookStore.length;i++) {
        if (book==BookStore[i].title) {
            var reply= prompt ('Want to add to your cart?'+ BookStore[i].title);
            if (reply==='yes') {
                Susan.cart.push(BookStore[i]);
                return "book added to cart."
            }else{
                return "book found, but not added to cart."
            }
        } 
    }
    return "bummer, book not found.";
}

alert(checkStore("book title"));
```

Answer (score 0):

## Fastest solution

This is the shortest way to take your exact existing code and add a few lines and solve this problem: `How to add to my existing code "if the string is not found, then alert the user 'not found!'".`

```
var checkStore=function (book) {
    var bookWasFound=false;                    //Line added here
    for (var i=0; i<BookStore.length;i++) {
        if (book==BookStore[i].title) {
            bookWasFound=true;                 //Line added here
            var reply= prompt ('Want to add to your cart?'+ BookStore[i].title);
            if (reply==='yes') {
                Susan.cart.push(BookStore[i]);
            }
        } 
    } 
    if (!bookWasFound) {                       //Line added here
        alert('Not found!');                   //Line added here
    }                                          //Line added here
}
```

---

## Explanation and alternatives

#### Why don't we use an `else` statement?

You ask, `"Do I used [else] statement[...]?"`

You do not. You ***can not***! The reason is because the `else` part of an `if-else` statement is executed when the `if` part is not executed. So if we put that in our loop, every time we compare a book title to the string we're looking for, our else would be executed if the book title didn't match. We only want that to happen once.

It is somewhat difficult to think about this scenario without a concrete example, so I will show what happens if we use an if-else statement.

The code would look like this:

```
if (book==BookStore[i].title) {
    ...
} else {
    alert('Not found!');
}
```

Imagine that our `BookStore` is populated with 3 books: `"The C Programming language"`, `"JavaScript: Pocket Reference"`, and `"Everybody Poops"`.
If the `checkStore` function is passed in `"JavaScript: Pocket Reference"`. Our loop will go like this:

As soon as we enter the loop, `book` would be equal to `"JavaScript: Pocket Reference"`, and `i = 0` so `BookStore[i].title` is the same as `BookStore[0].title`, and the 0th book's title is `"The C Programming language"`.

So the line `if(book==BookStore[i].title) {` would compare `"JavaScript: Poc..."` to `"The C Prog..."` and evaluate to false.
Since the `if` evaulated to false, the `else` part gets executed. The `else` part is `alert('Not found!')`.

Now, we have finished one iteration of our loop, and we compared the string passed in to the first book's title which didn't match, so we gave the alert. But we shouldn't have! If we just kept going, we would see that the second book's title matched, so we shouldn't have told the user that the book wasn't found. It is correct that the book wasn't found, ***yet***, but we should have waited before we announced this to the user.

I may have went into great detail to explain my point, but I believe it is very important. This is one example of when it takes **thinking like a programmer** or **thinking algorithmically** to solve the problem.

You have to think about the problem and ask yourself, `"How do we know if a book is in the list?"`. Well, a book is in the list if its title is the same as the title of any book in the list. Because we have to use the word ***any*** when we say `"...any book in the list"`, we know that our algorithm must test ***every*** book in the list.

We can't tell the user that a book was found, or not found, until we have tested every book in the list, or in our `BookStore`. We can't tell the user that a book was found, or not found, **until our loop has finished**.

---

#### So what do we do?

You will see this situation over and over again during your programming experience. You need to iterate over a list, and determine if *something* is in the list.

You can't ever know until you've iterated over every single object in the list, but once you have, how do you know the answer?

The solution is to use what is commonly referred to in programming, a **flag**. A **flag** is a variable that has two possible states: **true**, or **false**, **on** or **off**, **yes** or **no**, **1** or **0**. It doesn't matter what you call the states. At any time, the flag can only be in one of the two possible states.

We can use a flag by setting it to one state, usually **false** or **0**, then looping through some list and `if (...)` we set it to **true**. Each iteration of the loop, if some condition is met, we set our flag to **true**, and at the end of the loop, we know that the condition was met at some point in the loop, if the flag is **true**.

The most common way to implement a **flag**, is to use a boolean variable. That is, a variable which can only be set to **true** or **false**. In Javascript, there isn't a boolean variable since any variable can be set to any value. So we just use a regular variable, but still only set it to **true** or **false**.

We do that like this:

```
var myFlag = false;
// OR
var myFlag = true;
```

So a simple usage of a flag could be to determine if there exists an even number in a given array.
Just like this:

```
var myArray = [1, 3, 5, 123, 125, 4, 89, 8, 10];
var hasEven = false;

for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if( myArray[i] % 2 == 0 ) {
        hasEven = true;
    }
}

if(hasEven) {
    alert('Found an even number!');
} else {
    alert('Did not find an even number!');
}
```

**Note** that you can test the value of a boolean (true or false) variable with `if(variableName)`, you don't have to include the `== true` like `if(variableName == true)`.

---

## Final implementation

**Now we can use our `flag` to solve our original problem**

```
var checkStore = function(book) {
    var bookWasFound = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < BookStore.length; i++) {
        if (book == BookStore[i].title) {
            // If we get in this loop, we must have found a match,
            // so we should set our flag to true now
            bookWasFound = true

            var reply = prompt ('Want to add to your cart? ' + BookStore[i].title);
            if (reply === 'yes') {
                Susan.cart.push( BookStore[i] );
            }
        } // End of if statement for prompt

    } // End of loop looking for book

    if( !bookWasFound ) {    // Same as if( bookWasFound == false )
        alert('Not found!');
    } 

} // End of function
```

Using this flag allows us to keep the inside of the for loop very clean and organized, and handle the results outside of it.